# EXC BAD ACCESS in boost::thread join

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, exc-bad-access

I'm new to C++ and simply find what I'm doing wrong in this piece of code:

My C++ class looks like this:

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>

using namespace std;

struct AClass::AClassImpl
{
    boost::thread m_thread;
};

AClass::AClass(): pimpl (new AClass::AClassImpl) {}

AClass::~AClass() { delete pimpl; }

void AClass::start()
{
    cout << PREFIX << "main() : creating thread, " << endl;
    pimpl->m_thread = boost::thread(boost::bind(&AClass::process, this));
}

void AClass::stop()
{
    pimpl->m_thread.join();
}

void AClass::process()
{
    cout << PREFIX << "Hello World! Thread ID, " << endl;
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000));
    return;
}
```

In XCode I have also written an Objective-C test case that tests AClass with this method:

```
- (void) testStart
{
    tested->start();
    tested->stop();
}
```

The problem is that I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the

```
pimpl->m_thread.join();
```

line in the stop method.

This is my header file:

```
class AClass {
public:
    AClass ();
    ~AClass();
    void start();
    void stop();

private:
    struct AClassImpl; //fwd declaration of internal struct
    AClassImpl * pimpl; //opaque pointer
    void process();
};
```

Can anybody give me a hint on what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a deugger. Also, you either forgot to make your classes non-copyable or forgot to implement correct copy and assignment. Which I believe is what causing the problem (copying).

Comment: Thanks for you reply. maybe I'm just stupid but I don't see anywhere in the program where I'm doing a copy. Also I did try to debug it and when I'm in the stop function the thread seems fine as far as I can see..

Comment: Where is the `tested` object being created?

Comment: If one does not see the copy it is not guaranteed that its not there ;) It is guaranteed however, if you declare copy ctor and copy assignment private and don't implement them or just inherit from `boost::noncopyable`.

Comment: @pacoloco: First, make sure you don't by making your classes non-copyable (i.e. declare both copy constructor and assignment operator private). Because I am 95% sure that an accidental copy, when destroyed, wipes of your `pimpl` before you manage to call `join`.

Comment: Hmm copy constructor.. I added my header file in the question above. I was not aware that I needed a copy constructor.

Comment: Arne, can you explain more what you mean by "It is guaranteed however, if you declare copy ctor and copy assignment private and don't implement them" (which is my case above..)

Comment: Make pimpl `shared_ptr`. This should enable correct copying of `AClass`.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your program using

```
int main()
{
  AClass tested;
  tested.start();
  tested.stop();
  return 0;
}
```

and everything is working on trunk. The output is

```
main() : creating thread, 
Hello World! Thread ID,
```

I don't know how are you testing it. Could you try with my main?

Which version of Boost are you using, with which compiler and on which platform?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I haven't looked at this question for some time. I tested to run my code with a different compiler and there it worked for me as well. It only fails in XCode which is quite annoying as I'm doing the development on a Mac...